# cannot resolve method getText()

Tags: android

I'm new to Android developing and I'm trying to create a TODO list similar to an online tutorial I'm following.

Everything but "todoText.setText(todoList.get(position).getText());" compiles correctly.

With that line, I get the following error message: "cannot resolve method getText()."

This is part of a class responsible for displaying each list row in a TODO checklist:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    TextView todoText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.todoText);
    todoText.setText(todoList.get(position).getText());
    return rowView;
}
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing `todoList` declaration, but chances are that `todoList` is a `List` of `Strings` (or something else but a `TextView`). If that's the case, you may just need to do.-

```
todoText.setText(todoList.get(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the contents of your `todoList` but you can do a workaround if the content is not a String by using `.toString()`

Try to change the code into -

```
todoText.setText(todoList.get(position).toString());
```

hope it works.